# How do i select only specific words?

Tags: regex

With the string `ant apple bat` I want to select only `ant` and `bat` without selecting apple or any white space.

I've tried a few different things like;

```
\bant\b\bbat\b
```

or

```
ant\bbbat\b
```

or

```
(\b(ant)\b.*\b(bat)\b)
```

or

```
ant(?:.*)bat
```

or

```
ant(?:\sapple\s)bat
```

or

```
(ant)*[^a-z\s]*(bat)
```

I know the above examples are stupid but i'm just messing around on a regex tester trying to figure it out. I did regex before and I figured it out but can't seem to remember how i did it. Seems pretty simple just to select "ant" and "bat" but obviously not. Is there some way to deselect a match or to remove part of the match?

Comment: how about with non-caputring group `(ant) (?:apple) (bat)`

Comment: Or `\b(?:ant|bat)\b` https://regex101.com/r/h5WeTk/1

Answer (score 2):

Use a non capturing group with alternation:

```
(?:\bant\b|\bbat\b)
```

Comment: Or try `\b(ant|bat)\b`  .

Answer (score 0):

I guess you've understood it wrong.  A single regex match will match only contiguous text.  A simple regex like `ant|bat` with either match ant or bat.  But if you want to match ant and bat ignoring the text in between would not work.

When using regex with any programming languages like python or java, you would loop through the multiple matches and perform the action accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want two different words, that looks like this:

```
\b(ant|bat)\b
```

The `\b` is a word boundary
The parenthesis is a group
The pipe `|` is an or statement

- a word boundary
- followed by either the word `ant` or the word `bat`
- ending in a word boundary

A word boundary is probably what you would expect it to be, whitespace, end of a line, punctuation